# Как активировать окно "имя сети" в настройках подключения VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

Захожу в настройки сети в меню "сеть", но вкладка "имя сети" неактивна, гугление не дало результатов :) Что можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в поле выше вместо NAT (*ну или что там сейчас, у меня там NAT*) выбрать что-нибудь другое. Только потом не удивляться, если в гостевой машине вдруг не будет сети.

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендациюю) У самого стоит NAT, в этом был прокол.