# Неактивно окно "имя" в сети для адаптера - в Virtualbox - Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

У меня на виртуальной машине VirtualBox стоит Ubuntu. Настраиваю сеть по инструкции - вхожу в "файл" - "настройки" - "сеть" - "добавить сеть" - NatNetwork. Дальше в настройках - выбираю эту сеть ("настройки" - "сеть" - надпись "имя"); Но поле "имя" неактивно, хотя выбрана сеть "Nat". Как можно исправить?

Comment: дык, в случае nat'а оно и не должно быть активным…

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как активировать окно "имя сети" в настройках подключения VirtualBox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1377663/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-virtualbox)

Comment: Имеется инструкция, где имя созданной сети вбивается вручную.

Comment: «Тип подключения» должен быть «Сеть NAT», а не «NAT»… если считаешь, что у тебя всё правильно, то скрины в студию…

Comment: Вот рисунки для сетей. https://ibb.co/MpvGYBG
https://ibb.co/d5yzC1W
https://ibb.co/sQT4JGL

Comment: Ещё раз, на третьем скрине: _**«Тип подключения» должен быть «Сеть NAT», а не «NAT»…**_

Comment: Если я делаю сеть NAT, то в виртуальной машине, которую настраиваю, не открывается интернет активизацией Firefox.

Comment: это уже похоже на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710)… что именно ты делаешь и что именно хочешь сделать?

Comment: Привет всем. Я не специалист по настройки сети, но добиваюсь работы интернета в Ubuntu на машине VMWare. VMWare стоит на операционке Windows8. Но когда обнаруживаю там настройку NAT, вижу что требуется ввести имя сети. Но это имя ввести невозможно, хотя так должно быть.

Comment: пока ничего не понятно… для начала определись, virtualbox или vmware? и зачем тебе отдельная подсеть за NAT'ом?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133802/discussion-between-ivan-and-fat-zer).